# C - memory corruption with threads

Tags: c, pthreads, errno

I have a memory corruption that I have no clue what is happening.
There is a piece of my code:

```
void create_threads(t_data_thread *t, int max_threads){

int i;

/*Starts mutex */
if ((errno = pthread_mutex_init(&t->mutex, NULL)) != 0) // if I comment this if, 
ERROR(C_ERRO_MUTEX_INIT, "pthread_mutex_init() failed!"); // the code runs

/* Initializate the condition variable*/
if ((errno = pthread_cond_init(&t->cond, NULL)) != 0)
ERROR(C_ERRO_CONDITION_INIT, "pthread_cond_init() failed!");
t->total = 0;
t->writing_index = 0;
t->reading_index = 0;
t->stop = 0;


t->thread_count = MIN(t->num_files, max_threads);


pthread_t * tids = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*t->thread_count); // memorry corruption...

exit(0); // <- for test what is making the error
t->buffer = malloc(sizeof(char*) * t->thread_count*2);


for (i = 0; i < t->thread_count; i++){ 
if ((errno = pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, consumer, t)) != 0)
  ERROR(C_ERRO_PTHREAD_CREATE, "pthread_create() failed!"); 
}

producer(t);

/* Enter critical section */ 
if ((errno = pthread_mutex_lock(&(t->mutex))) != 0) {
 WARNING("pthread_mutex_lock() failed");
}

t->stop = 1;  

/* broadcast waiting threads */
if ((errno = pthread_cond_broadcast(&(t->cond))) != 0) {
 WARNING("pthread_cond_signal() failed");
```

I have no clue what is happening, if i comment:

> if ((errno = pthread_mutex_init(&t->mutex, NULL)) != 0) // if I comment this if, 
>       ERROR(C_ERRO_MUTEX_INIT, "pthread_mutex_init() failed!");

The code runs but then will fail on mutex... I also imported errno lib...
Thank You in advance!

t allocation:

```
t_data_thread *t = malloc(sizeof(t_data));
t->thread_count = maxThreads;
t->num_files = 0;
```

then on other function:

```
t-> num_files =0;
t->filesArray = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

and inside a loop i got:

```
t->filesArray = realloc(t->filesArray, (t->num_files + 1) * sizeof(char*));

t->filesArray[t->num_files] = strdup(str);
t->num_files++;
```

The structure:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char **wordsArray;
    int wordCounter;
    int sizeInbyte;
    long int curPos;   
    int num_files;
    char **buffer; 
    int writing_index;
    int reading_index;
    int total;
    int stop;
    int thread_count;
    char **filesArray;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
}t_data_thread;
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be writing to `errno` like that, though it probably isn't the cause of the trouble, either.  Are you doing this before or after you've created threads?  Where is the `pthread_create()` executed in relation to this code? Also, the definition of the `t->mutex` element of your `t_data_thread` structure might be relevant.  Do you get any compiler warnings when you compile?  Are you using GCC and using at least `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`?

Comment: pthread_create() comes after this code and my mutex on the struct is pthread_mutex_t... if you want I can post more code...
I'm using -Wall -W -Wmissing-prototypes

Comment: I had a feeling that `pthread_create()` came later.  How is `t` allocated in the calling code?  The `-W` is an old name for `-Wextra`, AFAICR.  So, if there are no unexplained warnings from the code, the chances are there isn't a compiler-detectable problem.  So, analyzing how `t` is created in the calling function may be relevant.  If you post more code, please show the definition/allocation of `t`, and the actual call to the function you do show. (I assume your comment "I also imported errno lib" means you have `#include <errno.h>` in your code.  It's a header, not really a library.)

Comment: And *what* comprises a `t_data_thread` ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added more some code. WhozCraig, I will post the struct

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(t_data));` - please check `t_data` and tell us you're *not* hiding a `t_data_thread*` *pointer* type in a `typedef`. Then fix the `malloc` to be `malloc(sizeof(*t));` Edit: ok, we see `t_data_thread`. Now what is a `t_data` ?

Comment: t_data was another structure that I had, I missed that and I didnt notice... thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superficially, your problem is:

```
t_data_thread *t = malloc(sizeof(t_data));
```

Presumably, you have a type `t_data`, but it is unrelated to `t_data_thread`.

A common idiom to avoid such problems is:

```
t_data_thread *t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
```

I trust you skipped showing the code that checked that the allocation was successful.

Comment: Really... such a dumb mistake... t_data is another struct for when im not using threads... Thank you very much and sorry about this post

Comment: These things happen, and an extra pair of eyes can help.  So can idioms that avoid the problem in the first place, of course.

Comment: Heh. had to check that you already had your Naruto hat before up-ticking this =P